# Create a common library in Play framework

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I created 3 subprojects in play: A,B, and common

A and B needs to use common subproject.
the code looks like this for the build.sbt:

```
name := """play"""
organization := "com.play"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val common = (project in file("modules/common")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

lazy val A = (project in file("modules/A")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
 .dependsOn(common).aggregate(common)
lazy val B= (project in file("modules/B")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
                .dependsOn(common).aggregate(common)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
            .dependsOn(A).aggregate(A)
            .dependsOn(B).aggregate(B)


scalaVersion := "2.11.11"


libraryDependencies += filters
libraryDependencies += evolutions
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "2.0.0" % Test
```

The package system, I follow the documentation in the Play framework which is like "package.moduleName"
So, the class in model package in my common subproject has a package name called: "model.common"

Now in subproject A, i want to call the library in the common subproject

I call like this:

```
import model.common.className
```

I cannot find it

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the classes inside a top level package.
For example for the common project you can put all the classes inside the `com.play.common` package.

After that you can use the class `example`(declare in the common project) from the project A using `import com.play.common.A`.